# Android ClassNotFoundException after making app compatible with Android 13

Tags: java, android, gradle

I recently made my Android app compatible with Android 13. After removing the OneSignal dependency and releasing the application, I'm encountering a crash with the following stack trace:

```
Crash Log:
BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Did not find class "com.abupdate.iot_libs.receiver.UpgradeReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename.app-UI3cN5rd405Zw-SeQbCPTQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename.app-UI3cN5rd405Zw-SeQbCPTQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.packagename.app-UI3cN5rd405Zw-SeQbCPTQ==/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename.app-UI3cN5rd405Zw-SeQbCPTQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.packagename.app-UI3cN5rd405Zw-SeQbCPTQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename.app-UI3cN5rd405Zw-SeQbCPTQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.packagename.app-UI3cN5rd405Zw-SeQbCPTQ==/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (CoreComponentFactory.java:60)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3429)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:201)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1690)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6861)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
...
```

**Context:**

- **Dependency:** I removed the OneSignal dependency.
- **Android Version:** The crash occurs after making the app compatible with Android 13.
- **Multidex Configuration:** I'm using the following multidex dependency and have set `multiDexEnabled true` in my app's gradle: `androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1`.

**Issue:**

Despite removing the OneSignal dependency and configuring multidex, I'm still encountering a `ClassNotFoundException` related to the class `com.abupdate.iot_libs.receiver.UpgradeReceiver`.

**Question:**

1. How can I resolve this `ClassNotFoundException` issue in the context of making my app compatible with Android 13?
2. Are there additional steps or considerations when updating an app for Android 13 that I might be missing?

**Additional Information:**

- **Crash Reporting:** I'm using Crashlytics for crash reporting, and the issue persists even after removing the OneSignal dependency.
- **Gradle Configuration:** Below is a snippet of my app's gradle configuration related to dependencies:

```
// Other dependencies...
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
// Other configurations...
```

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Does this crash happen when you compile your application and run it locally?

Comment: Many a times, ProGuard is the culprit in such cases. Do you have the code shrinking enabled?

Comment: No, I didn't face it personally. But recently there is spike on the Crashlytics. @tomerpacific

Comment: @Sujal Kumar
Code shrinking is disabled